# Can someone paraphrase this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

"How much one enjoys himself travelling depends largely on who he goes with, **whether his friends or relatives**."

Can someone paraphrase this sentence? I am confused about "whether his friends or relatives".

Answer (score 1):

See this conversation. I have tried to simplify the sentence in concern.

> How much do you enjoy traveling? ~ It depends.
>
> What do you mean?
>
> I mean it depends. If I'm with my friends, I enjoy it more. If I'm with my relatives, I don't enjoy myself that much!

*Whether his friends or relatives* introduces two options *he* goes with. And, depending largely on that, *he* would enjoy himself more or less while travelling.

Comment: -1 because either of those errors would have been sufficient for me to refrain from actually upvoting. Having both in one answer is just OTT.

Comment: The errors seem to be fixed now, though, thanks to StoneyB.

Answer (score 1):

This is my best interpretation:

> "The amount of enjoyment one derives from travel depends, for the most
>   part, on one's travel companions, regardless of whether these are
>   one's friends or relatives."

However, I would never use "whether" in this way. It's confusing because it's not clear whether it's meant to restrict the company to friends and family as a condition for enjoyment, or whether it admits their presence as a last resort, and means "despite" them.

Comment: Interesting interpretation — I hadn't considered that ambiguity!